# Are there any custom fuctions of AutoMapper to solve Mapping Problem?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, automapper

I'm trying to map some entities to DTOs and some DTOs to entities by AutoMapper 8.0.0.

This is my AutoMapper definition to map Entity to DTO. I was able to map Entities to DTOs by the definition below.

But When I try to map DTOs to Entities by reversing Recipe and RecipeDTO, I was not be able to map. I got error.

How Should I define automapper initialize to be able to realize this ?

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Recipe, RecipeDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Directions, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>     
    src.Directions))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Ingredients, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
    src.Ingredients))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Categories, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
    src.Categories.Select(i => i.Name)));
});
```

These are my entities and DTO'S

```
public class Recipe
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int DirectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Direction Directions { get; set; }

    public override DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public override string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public override DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public override string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories{get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients{get; set;}
}


public class Direction
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string Step { get; set; } 

    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

    public override DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public override string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public override DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public override string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public override DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public override string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public override DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public override string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set;}
}


public class Ingredient
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public override DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public override string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public override DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public override string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int AmountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Amount Amount { get; set; }

    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}

public class Amount
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public override DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public override string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public override DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public override string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeDTO
{   
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }

    public List<IngredientDTO> Ingredients { get; set; }

    public DirectionDTO Directions { get; set; }
} 

public class DirectionDTO
{
    public string Step { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientDTO
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public AmountDTO Amount { get; set; }
}

public class AmountDTO
{
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: You shouldn't need `ForMember` for properties that have the same name in both places.

Comment: I think the issue would be the Categories to List<string> rather than a List<CategoryDTO>.  Generally though I only use AutoMapper for Entity to DTO, not  reverse since in most cases you will want to associate entities for new/updated entities, not transform DTOs into what EF will essentially consider as new entities.